# VS2013 cannot add item to package

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-2013, package-managers, sharepoint-feature

I'm using VS2013 to development and maintain a couple of SP2013 projects. However, I think somehow I managed to corrupt one of the projects.

When I go to the "Package.package" designer, I see only (mapped SP) folders in there (it should also include the feature of the project). When I double-click, thus remove, one of these and try to re-add it, I get the following error msg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKD7k.png

Same goes when I try to add the feature to the package

What's also strange is that if I go into the Feature designer, I cannot add any items. VS gives a similar type of err msg:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4hJ8.png

Few more details:

- the projects were SP2010 projects and I successfully converted these to SP2013 some time ago.
- using Visual Studio Premium 2013, Update 3, running as an administrator.
- tried removing the feature and re-adding it; did not help.
- tried running VS in safe mode, resetting the user settings via the command line devenv; did not help.
- tried closing the designer, VS, rebooting; did not help.
- i am able to add/remove items to the package/feature in other projects so I suspect it not to be a VS2013 bug

Comment: Having the same problem. Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I ended up deleting the project and recreating it :(

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same Issue when adding items to feature or including features in package. I solved it by updating Visual Studio 2013 Developer Tools.

After updating to: `Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2013 - August 2015 update`